# Maven dependency versions conflict (google.protobuf)

Tags: maven, maven-shade-plugin

I have a project which use `org.openstreetmap.osmosis` and `spark` dependencies. All of them have a `com.google.protobuf` intern dependency, but require the different versions of it. When I build my project, Maven choose one of those sub-dependencies and the further execution results in a runtime error. Unfortunately it doesn't help to explicitly declare the dependency of `protobuf` neither.

I've heard it was a good idea to use `maven shade plugin`, but I can't configure it well. Could somebody please help me?

Sketch of using shade plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId> org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.2</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <relocations>
                    <relocation>
                        <pattern>com.google.protobuf</pattern>
                        <shadedPattern>${project.groupId}.${project.artifactId}.shaded.protobuf</shadedPattern>
                    </relocation>
                </relocations>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Unfortunately major releases of protobuf are not generally backward compatible. You could try building your own version of Apache Spark with a protobuf updated, or the opposite with Osmosis. Alternatively, does your application really need the Osmosis protobuf support?

Comment: @SteveC thank you! yes, unfortunately for osmosis it is an essential part: I have to read and parse a pbf-archive and this dependency is used for it

Comment: The Apache Spark parent pom (2.4.4) says "In theory we need not directly depend on protobuf since Spark does not directly use it. ...". It seems like it is required for Mesos.Sso if you're not using Mesos you might try simply excluding it.

Comment: @SteveC unfortunately we do use it :( I will take the note on it, because we are inclined to dismiss it in future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shade plugin cannot help here. Quoting it's documentation:

> This plugin provides the capability to package the artifact in an uber-jar, including its dependencies and to shade - i.e. rename - the packages of some of the dependencies

This is not what you need. You need to separate classpath with one version of protobuf from classpath with another version. This is a complicated thing, you'd have to play around with classloaders or some modularizarion mechanism like OSGi.

But I'd try first to just explicitly declare newest version of those two protobuf versions, and check if it is backward compatible.

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately it didn't work for me. Those libraries are in the base of both spark and osmosis and require thair version of it.